# VScode in manjaro is not recognizing installed jdk

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, archlinux, manjaro

I have jdk installed in manjaro but VScode extensions are not recoginizing the installed jdk...
I have used `archlinux-java status` and got this:

```
  java-14-openjdk
  java-8-openjdk (default)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:
Make sure you have right jdk installed u need two packages:
[1] **jdk-openjdk** and
[2] **jre-openjdk**
Second: you will have to set your newly installed jdk as default by putting this command in terminal:

```
 sudo archlinux-java set java-[version_number]-openjdk
```

Comment: I doubt you need the jre too

Comment: @Marged maybe not but its good to leave no chance of error....